# Factoring a Special Trinomial involving Roots of Unity

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Difference of two squares can be written in terms of roots of unity:

$$a^2-b^2=a^2+i^2b^2=a^2+(ib)^2=(a+b)(a+i^2b)=(a+b)(a-b)$$

Is there a way to factor either of the following then as a product of 2, 3, or more trinomials below?

> $$a^3+\omega_3b^3+\omega_3^2c^3$$
>   $$a^3+\omega_3^2b^3+\omega_3c^3$$

Here, $\omega_3=\exp(2i\pi/3)$.  It is algebraically easy to show that, for example,

$$(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)=(a+b+c)(a+\omega_3^2b+\omega_3c)(a+\omega_3b+\omega_3^2c)$$

But this is not the form I was looking for as there is the obvious shift by $3abc$.  It comes down to solving a system of equations thats nasty:

$$r_1r_2r_3=1, s_1s_2s_3=\omega_3,t_1t_2t_3=\omega_3^2$$
$$r_1r_2s_3+r_1r_3s_2+r_2r_3s_1=r_1r_2t_3+r_1r_3t_2+r_2r_3t_1=r_1s_2s_3+r_2s_1s_3+r_3s_1s_2$$
$$=s_1s_2t_3+s_1s_3t_2+s_2s_3t_1=r_1t_2t_3+r_2t_1t_3+r_3t_1t_2=s_1t_2t_3+s_2t_1t_3+s_3t_1t_2$$
$$=r_1s_2t_3+r_2s_1t_3+r_1s_3t_2+r_2s_3t_1+r_3s_1t_2+r_3s_2t_1=0$$

Or perhaps easier is a symmetry that I"m missing...  Otherwise this has to be solved for $r_i, s_i, t_i$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: What are you trying to factor? Your question seems a little hard to parse.

Comment: I'm trying to factor the two expressions highlighted into products of trinomials involving a b and c.

Comment: You have 10 equations in 9 unknowns so it's unlikely that there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a full answer.*

I conjecture there is no solution since you have 10 equations in 9 unknowns, so only in special cases can there be a solution at all.

But would the following expression be helpful for your problem?:

$$
2 (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) = \\
(x+y)(x+\omega_3 y) (x + \omega_3^2 y) +\\
(x+z)(x+\omega_3 z) (x + \omega_3^2 z) +\\
(z+y)(z+\omega_3 y) (z + \omega_3^2 y) 
$$

This gives a factorization into 3 products of 3 binomials, which can be applied to your needs. E.g. in the first case, identify $2x^3 = a^3$, $2y^3 = \omega_3 b^3$, $2z^3 = \omega_3^2 c^3$. Likewise in the second case.